# OWSLib post request

Tags: python, filter, xml, request, owslib

I am trying to generate a post request with owslib python library. However, I am getting an error when trying to filter the result.

```
from owslib.fes import *
from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService

# Url and version settings
URL = 'wfsurl/geoserver/wfs'
version = '1.1.0'
wfs11 = WebFeatureService(url, version)

filter_1 = Or(filter_list)
filterxml = etree.tostring(filter_1.toXML()).decode("utf-8") # Trying to convert the expression to string, not really sure about that part

# Making the request
response = wfs11.getfeature(typename='namespace:feature', method='post', filter=filterxml, outputFormat='application/json')

# Error message
TypeError: Argument 'element' has incorrect type (expected lxml.etree._Element, got NoneType)
```

Request seemed to have have worked with get request, but since the data I am trying to retrieve got bigger, I need to make a post request.

Comment: what is `filter_main` set to? I would guess that the problem is that `filterxml` is `None`

Comment: It was filter_1, my mistake.

Comment: so that solved the issue? or we still need to know what `filterxml` is set to

Comment: It did not solve the issue.